# Aggregate a data frame on variance

Tags: r, aggregate

Say I have this data frame, df,

```
       Day    value

1  2012-06-10   552
2  2012-06-10  4850
3  2012-06-11  4642
4  2012-06-11  4132
5  2012-06-11  4190
6  2012-06-12  4186
7  2012-06-13  1139
8  2012-06-13   490
9  2012-06-13  5156
10 2012-06-13  4430
11 2012-06-13  4447
12 2012-06-14  4256
13 2012-06-14  3856
14 2012-06-14  1163
15 2012-06-17   564
16 2012-06-17  4866
17 2012-06-17  4421
18 2012-06-19  4206
19 2012-06-20  4272
20 2012-06-20  3993
21 2012-06-20  1211
22 2012-07-21   698
23 2012-07-21  5770
24 2012-07-21  5103
25 2012-07-21   775
26 2012-07-21  5140
27 2012-07-22  4868
```

I would like a to create a data.frame, dfvar, that would contain the daily variance: something like:

```
     Day       Variance

1  2012-06-10  9236402
2  2012-06-11   X
3  2012-06-12  4186
4  2012-06-13  1139
5  2012-06-14  4256
6  2012-06-17   564
7  2012-06-19  4206
8  2012-06-20  4272
9  2012-07-21   698
10 2012-07-22  4868
```

So for example, I computed it, the entry 
`dfvar$Variance[1] = var(c(552, 4850))`

I tried to do

```
dfvar <- aggregate(df, by = list(Day), FUN = var)
```

but this isn't the input I expected. I really want to have the variance of the values of the same day, without the other days...
Any ideas about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want ?

```
library(dplyr)
df%>%group_by(Day)%>%dplyr::summarise(Variance=var(value))#return NA if only one value within the group

          Day   Variance
       <fctr>      <dbl>
1  2012-06-10 9236402.00
2  2012-06-11   77961.33
3  2012-06-12         NA
4  2012-06-13 4615704.30
5  2012-06-14 2829816.33
6  2012-06-17 5596946.33
7  2012-06-19         NA
8  2012-06-20 2864514.33
9  2012-07-21 6422224.70
10 2012-07-22         NA
```

Comment: Exactly! Thank you I had no knowledge about this function :)

Comment: Glad to help !~